# How to access a class file in web project to silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

I am new to silverlight. I have a separate class file in web project and i have to access the class file in silverlight project xaml page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight runtime is separate from the full .Net runtime, so you can't use it directly.  Microsoft has come up with two options, that I know of, that allow you to share a single code base across platforms:

1. Use an [RIA service project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).  This will create copies of your files and generate a separate DLL for Silverlight.
2. Use [portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx).  This approach is preferable I think, as it allows you to share a single DLL that is compatible with Silverlight, .Net, (and also Windows Phone and XBox).

Comment: There is another way too.. adding files as a link, although you do have to be careful that it can be compiled against the Silverlight framework.